# Is it ever safe to call Volley from a thread other than the main UI thread?

Tags: android, android-volley

The Volley [`ImageLoader`](https://github.com/daj/volley/blob/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java#L186) enforces that requests should be initiated from the main UI thread:

```
public ImageContainer get(String requestUrl, ImageListener imageListener,
        int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    // only fulfill requests that were initiated from the main thread.
    throwIfNotOnMainThread();
```

I think this is to guarantee that the response callback happens on the main UI thread, presumably because there is an assumption that the caller will want to update the UI in the callback.

However, I want to use Volley from within my processing of a GCM notification, which only needs to send a PendingIntent, not update the UI directly.  I was wondering if it would be safe to remove the `throwIfNotOnMainThread()` in this particular situation.  I doubt that would be safe, but I'm wondering if anybody can give a good reason why?

(FYI, it looks like the [`RequestQueue`](https://github.com/daj/volley/blob/master/src/com/android/volley/RequestQueue.java) has synchronized access to `mCurrentRequests`, so there seems to be internal locking on the request queue inside Volley.)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise removing that protection since in the general use case of the `ImageContainer` does change the UI.

A better approach IMO would be to use the `RequestQueue` directly with a custom request and handle it the way you want.